# Mat-toolbar does not bind component variable to template

Tags: angular, angular-material

The angular material element toolbar does not accept a component variable that is hard coded when I use the two-way binding syntax.

It behaves like it is not there.

I have tried hard coding it in there, of course, that works. Two-way binding is one of the simpler ones, it should work!

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUser = 'charlmers';
```

```
<div style="height: 100vh;">
  <mat-toolbar color="accent">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <span>{{currentUser || 'no user'}}</span>
      <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

'no user' appears on the toolbar, but my actual string doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. There must be some other issue in your code. Do you see any error in your console?

Comment: @nash11 no errors but I do get this warning ***[Violation] 'DOMContentLoaded' handler took 206ms*** . Seems relevant, I am trying to load content to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If it is not working please check the console and let me know what is the error you are getting.

```html
 <div style="height: 100vh;">
  <mat-toolbar color="accent">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <span>{{currentUser ==''?'no user':currentUser}}</span>
      <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

Comment: If I use that then 'no user' is displayed. Which means currentUser is an empty string. Because if I change it to == null  or == undefined, no user is not there. @Soubhagya Jena

Comment: For this test cases, please try this {{currentUser ?currentUser:'no user'}}